# Is this a valid unit test for Hash Map?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I am trying to undarstand if I am writing unit test in the write way. I have a hashmap where I store my customer register. I am trying to write a unit test for my createCustomer metod. Can someone give me pointers if I am in the right direction?

```
void addCustomer () {
        System.out.println ();

        String customerName = getString ("Enter Customer Name with cappital letar: ");

        String customerAddress = getString ("Enter Customer Address with cappital letar: ");

        int customerPhone = getInt ("Enter Customer phone:");

        int customerID = checkID ();
        Customer customer = new Customer (customerName, customerAddress, customerID, customerPhone);
        customerList.put (customerID, customer);
        System.out.println ("Customer Added");

    }

@Test
    public void addCustomerTest () {
        HashMap<Integer,Customer> customerList = new HashMap<> ();
        String customerName = "Anna";
        String customerAddress = "London";
        int customerPhone =  1010101;

        int customerID = 1000;
        Customer customer = new Customer (customerName, customerAddress, customerID, customerPhone);
        customerList.put (customerID, customer);

        assertTrue(customerList.containsKey(customerID) && customerList.get(customerID) != null);

    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much off-topic for SO, but your test is exposing a design problem in your code. You are mixing UI, where you get multiple values from a user and then create an object with this state before saving it to a global somewhere. A unit test would just test the creation of a Customer object, where you assert that null or invalid arguments are correctly allowed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the `HashMap` author while currently you unit test this class.
So no you don't test in the right way your code.
What you want unit testing is the API of **your** class : that is `addCustomer()`.
The `Map` is an implementation detail that may change over the time and that you don't want to test.

Your unit test should look like :

```
@Test
public void addCustomer() {
    CustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository();
    String customerName = "Anna";
    String customerAddress = "London";
    int customerPhone =  1010101;
    int customerID = 1000;
    // Mock the System IN to read these values
    // ...
    // invoke the method under test
    repo.addCustomer();
    // assert that the repo contains the new object
    Customer actual = repo.findCustomerById(customerID);
    assertNotNull(actual);
    assertEquals(customerName, actual.getCustomerName());
    assertEquals(customerID, actual.getCustomerID());
    // and so for for each field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write a unit test you are **testing a unit of code that you wrote**.

In the test

```
@Test
public void addCustomerTest () {
    HashMap<Integer,Customer> customerList = new HashMap<> ();
    String customerName = "Anna";
    String customerAddress = "London";
    int customerPhone =  1010101;

    int customerID = 1000;
    Customer customer = new Customer (customerName, customerAddress, customerID, customerPhone);
    customerList.put (customerID, customer);

    assertTrue(customerList.containsKey(customerID) && customerList.get(customerID) != null);

}
```

you are not testing your code, but eventually you are testing the `HashMap`.

To write a good unit test you need to:

- **identify the method** that you wrote and that you like to test.
- if your method accept parameters **identify the border values** that can create problems to your code (for example a null value for an object, an empty list for a list, a maximum or minimum integer for an int)
- **write a test** to check if your code works **for those special values**
- **write one test** to check if it works with **normal values**

If all works you can try to rewrite the code refactoring it to have a better design, following the [mantra](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/tdd-red-green-refactor)

- **RED** - think about what you want to develop
- **GREEN** - think about how to make your tests pass
- **Refactor** - think about how to improve your existing implementation

then add new tests and follow again the process red, green, refactor.

Comment: So I should write: hashmap.size() +1 equals hashmap.size ? Is that correct?